# How i can connect websocket wss:// delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

i have a server websocket, how to connect my server in Delphi?

example in javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Websocket functions
      function connectWebSocket() {
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
                  // Create new websocket connection
                  ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080");

                  // Called after connection is established
                  ws.onopen = function() {
                        enableInputs(true);
                        logMsg('Connected to: ' + ws.URL);

                  };

                  // Called when a new message is received
                  ws.onmessage = function (msg) { 
                        if (msg.data) {
                              logMsg(msg.data);
                        }
                  };

                  // Called when connection is closed
                  ws.onclose = function() { 
                        enableInputs(false);
                        logMsg("Connection closed!"); 
                  };
            } else {
                  logMsg('Browser doesn\'t support websockets!');
            }
      }
</script>
```

I tested the IP*WORKS!, but it is paid, there is another alternative?

Comment: I've been looking into it for the [xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/) project, but haven't got it working yet.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/bin/public/xxmWebSocket.pas) is what I have so far. "ws://" works, to get "wss://" I really need to create TLS support in xxmHttp...